# Parsing ascii, escaped JSON string Python 3.6

Tags: python, json, encode

I have received the a giant string to parse into json, I have narrowed the error to this small case, take:

```
t = "b'{\"t\":\"a\"}'"
```

then call:

```
t = str(t)
json.loads(t)
```

and it gives the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "json_dump.py", line 11, in
>   
>       json.loads(t)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/**init**.py", line 354, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
>       raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0)

it seems to me that the `b` means its in `ascii`. Everything else is escaped correctly as far as I can tell. I can't really understand why `json` lib has a problem here.

For further context, here is the code being run in AWS:

```
import base64
import json
import zlib
import aws_encryption_sdk
from aws_encryption_sdk.internal.crypto import WrappingKey
from aws_encryption_sdk.key_providers.raw import RawMasterKeyProvider
from aws_encryption_sdk.identifiers import WrappingAlgorithm, EncryptionKeyType
import boto3

REGION_NAME = '<region>'                    # us-east-1
RESOURCE_ID = '<external-resource-id>'      # cluster-ABCD123456
STREAM_NAME = 'aws-rds-das-' + RESOURCE_ID  # aws-rds-das-cluster-ABCD123456


class MyRawMasterKeyProvider(RawMasterKeyProvider):
    provider_id = "BC"

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(RawMasterKeyProvider, cls).__new__(cls)
        return obj

    def __init__(self, plain_key):
        RawMasterKeyProvider.__init__(self)
        self.wrapping_key = WrappingKey(wrapping_algorithm=WrappingAlgorithm.AES_256_GCM_IV12_TAG16_NO_PADDING,
                                        wrapping_key=plain_key, wrapping_key_type=EncryptionKeyType.SYMMETRIC)

    def _get_raw_key(self, key_id):
        return self.wrapping_key


def decrypt_payload(payload, data_key):
    my_key_provider = MyRawMasterKeyProvider(data_key)
    my_key_provider.add_master_key("DataKey")
    decrypted_plaintext, header = aws_encryption_sdk.decrypt(
        source=payload,
        materials_manager=aws_encryption_sdk.DefaultCryptoMaterialsManager(master_key_provider=my_key_provider))
    return decrypted_plaintext


def decrypt_decompress(payload, key):
    decrypted = decrypt_payload(payload, key)
    return zlib.decompress(decrypted, zlib.MAX_WBITS + 1)


def main():
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    kms = session.client('kms', region_name=REGION_NAME)
    kinesis = session.client('kinesis', region_name=REGION_NAME)

    response = kinesis.describe_stream(StreamName=STREAM_NAME)
    shard_iters = []
    for shard in response['StreamDescription']['Shards']:
        shard_iter_response = kinesis.get_shard_iterator(StreamName=STREAM_NAME, ShardId=shard['ShardId'],
                                                         ShardIteratorType='LATEST')
        shard_iters.append(shard_iter_response['ShardIterator'])

    while len(shard_iters) > 0:
        next_shard_iters = []
        for shard_iter in shard_iters:
            response = kinesis.get_records(ShardIterator=shard_iter, Limit=10000)
            for record in response['Records']:
                record_data = record['Data']
                record_data = json.loads(record_data)
                payload_decoded = base64.b64decode(record_data['databaseActivityEvents'])
                data_key_decoded = base64.b64decode(record_data['key'])
                data_key_decrypt_result = kms.decrypt(CiphertextBlob=data_key_decoded,
                                                      EncryptionContext={'aws:rds:dbc-id': RESOURCE_ID})
                print decrypt_decompress(payload_decoded, data_key_decrypt_result['Plaintext'])
            if 'NextShardIterator' in response:
                next_shard_iters.append(response['NextShardIterator'])
        shard_iters = next_shard_iters


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and here is the error returned from the lambda:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "b'{\"type\":\"DatabaseActivityMonitoringRecord\",\"clusterId\":\"cluster-AB5DDGRPE66FSNLZ3ZVTQLKVCY\",\"instanceId\":\"db-56OMGOMNHB73GQDRZJ7PUCYC5Y\",\"databaseActivityEventList\":[{\"logTime\":\"2019-10-07 04:36:48.067795+00\",\"statementId\":20,\"substatementId\":1,\"objectType\":\"TABLE\",\"command\":\"UPDATE\",\"objectName\":\"public.option\",\"databaseName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"dbUserName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"remoteHost\":\"10.180.34.89\",\"remotePort\":\"38864\",\"sessionId\":\"5d9ac0ce.2de2\",\"rowCount\":1,\"commandText\":\"SELECT 1 FROM ONLY \\\\\"public\\\\\".\\\\\"option\\\\\" x WHERE \\\\\"id\\\\\" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x\",\"paramList\":[\"913287\"],\"pid\":11746,\"clientApplication\":\"\",\"exitCode\":null,\"class\":\"WRITE\",\"serverVersion\":\"2.3.5\",\"serverType\":\"PostgreSQL\",\"serviceName\":\"Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible edition\",\"serverHost\":\"10.180.24.201\",\"netProtocol\":\"TCP\",\"dbProtocol\":\"Postgres 3.0\",\"type\":\"record\"},{\"logTime\":\"2019-10-07 04:36:48.145962+00\",\"statementId\":53,\"substatementId\":1,\"objectType\":\"TABLE\",\"command\":\"SELECT\",\"objectName\":\"public.dealer_option\",\"databaseName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"dbUserName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"remoteHost\":\"10.180.34.162\",\"remotePort\":\"39320\",\"sessionId\":\"5d9ac0c7.2d52\",\"rowCount\":1,\"commandText\":\"SELECT *\\\\n\\\\tFROM dealer_option\\\\n\\\\tWHERE name=$1\\\\n\\\\tAND dealer_option_category_id=$2\\\\n\",\"paramList\":[\"Driver door bin\",\"1\"],\"pid\":11602,\"clientApplication\":\"\",\"exitCode\":null,\"class\":\"READ\",\"serverVersion\":\"2.3.5\",\"serverType\":\"PostgreSQL\",\"serviceName\":\"Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible edition\",\"serverHost\":\"10.180.24.201\",\"netProtocol\":\"TCP\",\"dbProtocol\":\"Postgres 3.0\",\"type\":\"record\"},{\"logTime\":\"2019-10-07 04:36:48.147649+00\",\"statementId\":29,\"substatementId\":1,\"objectType\":\"TABLE\",\"command\":\"SELECT\",\"objectName\":\"public.option\",\"databaseName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"dbUserName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"remoteHost\":\"10.180.37.127\",\"remotePort\":\"54256\",\"sessionId\":\"5d9ac09b.2926\",\"rowCount\":1,\"commandText\":\"SELECT *\\\\n\\\\tFROM option\\\\n\\\\tWHERE option_id=uuid($1::TEXT)\\\\n\",\"paramList\":[\"893a662f-fb09-4d1e-b182-8f0581f64ad9\"],\"pid\":10534,\"clientApplication\":\"\",\"exitCode\":null,\"class\":\"READ\",\"serverVersion\":\"2.3.5\",\"serverType\":\"PostgreSQL\",\"serviceName\":\"Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible edition\",\"serverHost\":\"10.180.24.201\",\"netProtocol\":\"TCP\",\"dbProtocol\":\"Postgres 3.0\",\"type\":\"record\"},{\"logTime\":\"2019-10-07 04:36:48.17333+00\",\"statementId\":84,\"substatementId\":1,\"objectType\":\"TABLE\",\"command\":\"SELECT\",\"objectName\":\"public.dealer_option\",\"databaseName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"dbUserName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"remoteHost\":\"10.180.27.4\",\"remotePort\":\"45034\",\"sessionId\":\"5d9ac0af.2aa8\",\"rowCount\":1,\"commandText\":\"SELECT *\\\\n\\\\tFROM dealer_option\\\\n\\\\tWHERE name=$1\\\\n\\\\tAND dealer_option_category_id=$2\\\\n\",\"paramList\":[\"Child-Safety Locks\",\"49\"],\"pid\":10920,\"clientApplication\":\"\",\"exitCode\":null,\"class\":\"READ\",\"serverVersion\":\"2.3.5\",\"serverType\":\"PostgreSQL\",\"serviceName\":\"Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible edition\",\"serverHost\":\"10.180.24.201\",\"netProtocol\":\"TCP\",\"dbProtocol\":\"Postgres 3.0\",\"type\":\"record\"},{\"logTime\":\"2019-10-07 04:36:48.177203+00\",\"statementId\":86,\"substatementId\":1,\"objectType\":\"TABLE\",\"command\":\"SELECT\",\"objectName\":\"public.dealer_option\",\"databaseName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"dbUserName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"remoteHost\":\"10.180.27.4\",\"remotePort\":\"45042\",\"sessionId\":\"5d9ac0af.2aac\",\"rowCount\":1,\"commandText\":\"SELECT *\\\\n\\\\tFROM dealer_option\\\\n\\\\tWHERE name=$1\\\\n\\\\tAND dealer_option_category_id=$2\\\\n\",\"paramList\":[\"Passenger Air Bag\",\"49\"],\"pid\":10924,\"clientApplication\":\"\",\"exitCode\":null,\"class\":\"READ\",\"serverVersion\":\"2.3.5\",\"serverType\":\"PostgreSQL\",\"serviceName\":\"Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible edition\",\"serverHost\":\"10.180.24.201\",\"netProtocol\":\"TCP\",\"dbProtocol\":\"Postgres 3.0\",\"type\":\"record\"},{\"logTime\":\"2019-10-07 04:36:48.1793+00\",\"statementId\":201,\"substatementId\":1,\"objectType\":\"TABLE\",\"command\":\"SELECT\",\"objectName\":\"public.dealer_option\",\"databaseName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"dbUserName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"remoteHost\":\"10.180.39.59\",\"remotePort\":\"60488\",\"sessionId\":\"5d9ac071.2620\",\"rowCount\":1,\"commandText\":\"SELECT *\\\\n\\\\tFROM dealer_option\\\\n\\\\tWHERE name=$1\\\\n\\\\tAND dealer_option_category_id=$2\\\\n\",\"paramList\":[\"Cruise Control\",\"1\"],\"pid\":9760,\"clientApplication\":\"\",\"exitCode\":null,\"class\":\"READ\",\"serverVersion\":\"2.3.5\",\"serverType\":\"PostgreSQL\",\"serviceName\":\"Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible edition\",\"serverHost\":\"10.180.24.201\",\"netProtocol\":\"TCP\",\"dbProtocol\":\"Postgres 3.0\",\"type\":\"record\"},{\"logTime\":\"2019-10-07 04:36:48.181394+00\",\"statementId\":32,\"substatementId\":1,\"objectType\":\"TABLE\",\"command\":\"SELECT\",\"objectName\":\"public.option\",\"databaseName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"dbUserName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"remoteHost\":\"10.180.37.127\",\"remotePort\":\"54258\",\"sessionId\":\"5d9ac09b.2927\",\"rowCount\":1,\"commandText\":\"SELECT *\\\\n\\\\tFROM option\\\\n\\\\tWHERE option_id=uuid($1::TEXT)\\\\n\",\"paramList\":[\"89d25110-8655-4bc7-8c70-661f7f884be6\"],\"pid\":10535,\"clientApplication\":\"\",\"exitCode\":null,\"class\":\"READ\",\"serverVersion\":\"2.3.5\",\"serverType\":\"PostgreSQL\",\"serviceName\":\"Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible edition\",\"serverHost\":\"10.180.24.201\",\"netProtocol\":\"TCP\",\"dbProtocol\":\"Postgres 3.0\",\"type\":\"record\"},{\"logTime\":\"2019-10-07 04:36:48.195299+00\",\"statementId\":37,\"substatementId\":1,\"objectType\":\"TABLE\",\"command\":\"SELECT\",\"objectName\":\"public.dealer_option\",\"databaseName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"dbUserName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"remoteHost\":\"10.180.34.162\",\"remotePort\":\"39318\",\"sessionId\":\"5d9ac0c7.2d51\",\"rowCount\":1,\"commandText\":\"SELECT *\\\\n\\\\tFROM dealer_option\\\\n\\\\tWHERE name=$1\\\\n\\\\tAND dealer_option_category_id=$2\\\\n\",\"paramList\":[\"Front Center Armrest\",\"1\"],\"pid\":11601,\"clientApplication\":\"\",\"exitCode\":null,\"class\":\"READ\",\"serverVersion\":\"2.3.5\",\"serverType\":\"PostgreSQL\",\"serviceName\":\"Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible edition\",\"serverHost\":\"10.180.24.201\",\"netProtocol\":\"TCP\",\"dbProtocol\":\"Postgres 3.0\",\"type\":\"record\"},{\"logTime\":\"2019-10-07 04:36:48.2033+00\",\"statementId\":80,\"substatementId\":1,\"objectType\":\"TABLE\",\"command\":\"SELECT\",\"objectName\":\"public.dealer_option\",\"databaseName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"dbUserName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"remoteHost\":\"10.180.34.162\",\"remotePort\":\"45148\",\"sessionId\":\"5d9ac0b1.2ae9\",\"rowCount\":1,\"commandText\":\"SELECT *\\\\n\\\\tFROM dealer_option\\\\n\\\\tWHERE name=$1\\\\n\\\\tAND dealer_option_category_id=$2\\\\n\",\"paramList\":[\"Illuminated Visor Mirror\",\"49\"],\"pid\":10985,\"clientApplication\":\"\",\"exitCode\":null,\"class\":\"READ\",\"serverVersion\":\"2.3.5\",\"serverType\":\"PostgreSQL\",\"serviceName\":\"Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible edition\",\"serverHost\":\"10.180.24.201\",\"netProtocol\":\"TCP\",\"dbProtocol\":\"Postgres 3.0\",\"type\":\"record\"},{\"logTime\":\"2019-10-07 04:36:48.2033+00\",\"statementId\":85,\"substatementId\":1,\"objectType\":\"TABLE\",\"command\":\"SELECT\",\"objectName\":\"public.dealer_option\",\"databaseName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"dbUserName\":\"metal_api_prototype\",\"remoteHost\":\"10.180.34.54\",\"remotePort\":\"46688\",\"sessionId\":\"5d9ac0b0.2ae1\",\"rowCount\":1,\"commandText\":\"SELECT *\\\\n\\\\tFROM dealer_option\\\\n\\\\tWHERE name=$1\\\\n\\\\tAND dealer_option_category_id=$2\\\\n\",\"paramList\":[\"Rear Head Air Bag\",\"49\"],\"pid\":10977,\"clientApplication\":\"\",\"exitCode\":null,\"class\":\"READ\",\"serverVersion\":\"2.3.5\",\"serverType\":\"PostgreSQL\",\"serviceName\":\"Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible edition\",\"serverHost\":\"10.180.24.201\",\"netProtocol\":\"TCP\",\"dbProtocol\":\"Postgres 3.0\",\"type\":\"record\"}]}' is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py",
      238,
      "dumps",
      "**kw).encode(obj)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py",
      199,
      "encode",
      "chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py",
      257,
      "iterencode",
      "return _iterencode(o, 0)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py",
      134,
      "decimal_serializer",
      "raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: IMHO the `b` in front of the string is python stuff: `json.loads(eval("b'{\"t\":\"a\"}'"))` works correctly for me, but is really unsafe.

Comment: *"it seems to me that the `b` means its in ascii"* No, that's not what it means. The `b` **here** means nothing, it's the first character in a string. The `b` in front of a string means it's a byte string, but that's not even what you have here.

Comment: You need to show more context. Where/how is the source string stored, and how are you reading it?

Comment: `eval` scares me, the source is AWS so its fairly trusted but still. `t = str(t, encoding='ascii')` gives the following error: `TypeError: decoding str is not supported`

Comment: if the `"b'{}'"` is something repeatable, you can consider a slicing of the string: `json.loads(t[2:-1])`

Comment: Yeah `eval` must be avoided absolutely

Comment: @FrankConry because `decode` only makes sense on a bytes object, but you **already have a `str`**. Someone, somewhere in your data-pipeline has decided to incorrectly dump the *string representation* of a bytes data structure instead of the bytes object itself. You should fix that, if you can.

Comment: @MatteoRagni the source is coming from and AWS kinesis stream, so I don't want to arbitrarily chop off the first character. @Tomalak the three lines of code in the answer concisely replicate the problem. I get to this point after decrypting a message with `aws_encryption_sdk`

Comment: What is `type(t)` _before_ you call `str` on it?

Comment: Note, `t` *already is a `str`* in the example you've given, so `t = str(t)` really makes no sense, it is at the very least unnecessary and redundant. In any case, the problem is obvious: that string is not valid JSON. Copy and paste it into any JSON validator and you'll see that, the startin `b` should make that obvious

Comment: @FrankConry The three lines in the sample do not run, the variable `lil` is never defined. Independently of that, you need to supply more context. This is not a JSON parser problem. This is a "you likely read your data incorrectly" problem.

Comment: If you are not modifying the string coming from AWS, but you still get string that is `"b'{...}'"` (and not `b"{...}"`, there is a great difference) you have to get rid of a spurious `"b'"` at the beginning and `'` at the end of your string. But I'm pretty sure that you are making something like `str("{'t':'a'}".encode('ascii'))` that is causing you the troubles

Comment: @Tomalaksorry typo. fixed now. should be `json.loads(t)`

Comment: added AWS context. Error starts with `"b'{\"type\" ...`

Comment: So again, if that is just what is in your data, then your data was serialized incorrectly. What you are getting is not a valid JSON string, simple as that.

Comment: And you need to parse the json string in `"errorMessage"`? Then I'm sorry but IMHO you are forced into doing the slicing. AWS is doing `str(json_string.encode('utf-8'))` for you :S

Comment: @GarrGodfrey it is also how Python indicates a `bytes` object literal.

Comment: @MatteoRagni it could be that whatever uploads the data to AWS did something like that

Comment: ok, you guys solved my issue. The error message was quoting the string literal, so it was as @MatteoRagni said `b"{...}"` in the python, which can be cast directly as json. I think the error message was casting it as ascii and the `b` came along for the ride. how on earth do I give you guys points for it?

Comment: @FrankConry "casting" as "ascii" doesn't make any sense. ASCII isn't a type, it is an encoding. But the error message seems to indicate that it is occuring during the *encoding* into JSON...

Comment: @jaunpa.arrivillaga fair enough, what I mean is that it's a byte string in the code, but when creating the error message it gets converted to `"b'{...}'" from `b'{...}' hence my confusion.

Comment: Yes, but notice in the actual stack trace it isn't coming from `json.load`, it's coming from `json.dumps`

Comment: right. so since the string was already in a form that it I could call `json.loads` on it, I passed that from the lambda, so then when AWS called `json.dumps` on it it didn't fail.